# How to follow the next page but only up to a certain page in scrapy python

Tags: python, scrapy

So I am scraping some real estate prices but I only want the data before a certain date say 2010, which means I need to follow the next page only up to a certain page. How do I go about to achieve this?

I can get the page that I want to the follow link to stop at,  manually but obviously I want to avoid this.

Can we somehow utilise the number of items scraped? For example, in this website (given below), I am only scraping 10 items per page. Say I only want to scrape the data up to page 14 (including page 14 but not 15), then there should be 14 x 10  = 140 items scraped. Can I then tell scrapy to stop at when items scraped = 140?

```
import scrapy

class PropertySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'property'
    start_urls = ['http://house.speakingsame.com/p.php?q=Fortitude+Valley&p=0&s=1&st=&type=House&count=288&region=Fortitude+Valley&lat=0&lng=0&sta=qld&htype=&agent=0&minprice=0&maxprice=0&minbed=0&maxbed=0&minland=0&maxland=0'
                  ]

    def parse(self, response):

        # my code here

        next_page = response.xpath("/html/body/center/table").xpath(".//tr").xpath(".//td")[-1].css('a').attrib[
            'href']
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrapy provides the Close spider extension.

> class scrapy.extensions.closespider.CloseSpider
>
> > Closes a spider automatically when some conditions are met, using a specific closing reason for each condition.

By enabling the extension you get access to several settings that can be used to halt the spider at some point including `CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT` which will do exactly what you are asking.

In your settings.py file

```
EXTENSIONS = {
    'scrapy.extensions.closespider.CloseSpider': 500  
}

# CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT = 0   
CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT = 140 # change value to suite your needs
# CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT = 0
# CLOSESPIDER_ERRORCOUNT = 0
```

[Scrapy CloseSpider Docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#module-scrapy.extensions.closespider)